# StringToHex подскажите наиболее правильное исполнение?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

На данный момент использую сабж такого вида:

```
    public static String toHexString(byte[] ba) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < ba.length; i++) {
        str.append(ba[i]<16?"0":"")
            .append(String.format("%x",ba[i]).toUpperCase());
    }
    return str.toString().trim();
}
```

не могу сообразить, почему результат может оказаться таким:

```
00 00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 54 00 65 00 73 00 74 00 20 00 4D 00 65 00 73 00 73 00 61 00 67 00 65 00 00 00 0D2 04 00 00
```

Ведь D2 == 210 и явно больше 16...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина, а так же хотелось бы увидеть наиболее правильную, с Вашей точки зрения, реализацию сабжа.
Спасибо!

Comment: Уфф... Прошу прощения за глупость. Совсем вылетело из головы, что у формата можно использовать нечто вроде "%02x".
Вопрос по ошибке остается, для улучшения знания теории.
Вопрос про наилучший вариант так же остается.
Текст вопроса не исправляю.

Comment: Может, это поможет: http://stackoverflow.com/q/923863/276994

Исходя из ответов, "канонического" пути нет.

Comment: Стэк я читал на эту тему... Но, согласитесь, БигИнтеджер использовать для такой конвертации - верх програмистского гения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я использую такой вариант:

```
public static String bytesToHexString(byte[] array)
{
    char[] val = new char[2*array.length];
    String hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        int b = array[i] & 0xff;
        val[2*i] = hex.charAt(b >>> 4);
        val[2*i + 1] = hex.charAt(b & 15);
    }
    return String.valueOf(val);
}
```

P.S. А `String` на байты это совсем просто...

Comment: ты по ссылке видел решение 1 строчкой?

Comment: Видел, но использование BigInteger или апачевого пакета мне не кажется хорошей идеей...

Comment: 1 строчка которая ведет к бинарнику в мегабайт - это не очень хорошо...